# Query related to concatenation of output from for loop

Tags: python

I have to extract values from a list after doing some comparison. If my values are found in the list, then i need to concatenate the output with comma delimiter.

Below is the snapshot of my input data set and code I have written`

```
filter = ['abc', 'xyz']

data = [{'type': 'Cust',  'value': '71581742', 'loc': 'abc'}, {'type': 'Cust',  'value': '12345', 'loc': 'xyz'}, {'type': 'Cust',  'value': '76543', 'loc': 'tyu'}]
```

So, in short i need to check if all of the values provided in the "filter" are present in the "data". If found than i need to return "value" in one row only as show below:

'71581742','12345'

I tried with below code :

```
value1=""
for val in filter:
    value = str([x['value'] for x in data if val in x['loc']])[1:-1]
    value1=value1+','+value
    print(value1)
```

however output I am getting from it is

```
,'71581742'
,'71581742','12345'
```

I need output as '71581742','12345'

Can someone help me, and let me know what I am doing wrong

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
values = [x['value'] for x in data if x['loc'] in filter]
print(", ".join(values))
```

The reason why you get the out you have is, because you start with an empty string:

```
value1=""
```

The first time you go throught the loop and hit:

```
value1=value1+','+value
```

you concatenate an empty string, a comma and the new value, thus getting the result 
`,'71581742'`

Answer (score 0):

One first note: **avoid overwriting filter()**, that's a Python base function!!

```py
f = ['abc', 'xyz']

data = [{'loc': 'abc', 'type': 'Cust', 'value': '71581742'},
        {'loc': 'xyz', 'type': 'Cust', 'value': '12345'},
        {'loc': 'tyu', 'type': 'Cust', 'value': '76543'}]
```

Given that, you can define your own filter function like this. (Returns True of False)

```py
def data_filter(data, f):
    return data['loc'] in f
```

You can apply the filter to list comprehension, then join the result list with comma:

```py
res=[d['value'] for d in data if data_filter(d, f)]
print(','.join(res))
```

With this approach, you may even upgrade data_filter(), for example adding a key parameter, so that you can use that function with any other dictionary key.